# Sort bjobs output

Tags: linux, lsf

Is there a way to sort the bjobs output based on submit_time ?
Or according to some other field ?

`JOBID   USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME   SUBMIT_TIME`

Comment: This may help.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1021057

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
bjobs | sort
```

This will sort on the job ID which for me is dispersed in order. So this is effectively sorting by submit time.

Answer (score 0):

Not using bjobs directly.  However, if you reorder the bjobs output (man bjobs) to list start_time first and you can then pipe to sort.  Also, recommend '-noheader'